# Camel errorHandler / deadLetterChannel REST response

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Camel rest endpoint (Jetty) which validates and processes incoming requests. Besides specific Exception handlers (onException) it uses a DLQ  error handler (errorHandler(deadLetterChannel...)) which is setup to retry 3 times - if unsuccessful the message is moved to the DLQ.

My question is, how do I still return a user friendly error message back to the client if an unexpected Exception occurs rather than the full Exception body? Is there some config I'm missing on the errorHandler?
I've tried to find some examples on the camel unit tests (DeadLetterChannelHandledExampleTest) and camel in action 2 (Chapter 11) but none seemed to have specific examples for this scenario.

Code is:

`.from(ROUTE_URI)
        .errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("{{activemq.webhook.dlq.queue}}")
            .onPrepareFailure(new FailureProcessor())
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliveryDelay(1000))
            .bean(ParcelProcessor.class, "process");`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a 2nd route as the DLQ, eg `direct:dead` and then send the message first to the real DLQ, and then do the message transformation afterwards to return a friendly response.

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:dead")

from("direct:dead")
  .to("{{activemq.webhook.dlq.queue}}")
  .transform(constant("Sorry something was wrong"));
```